# Calling functions which are defined in other php file wont work the way I want

Tags: php, html

I have followin PHP code, it is where I defined my functions:

```
<?php
function emaili_pikkus($email){
    if (strlen($email)>45){
        echo 'e-mail ei tohi olla pikem kui 45 tähemärki';
    }
    else{
        $emaili_pikkus=True;
    }
}

function parooli_pikkus($parool)
    {
    $pikkus = strlen($parool);
    if ($pikkus<6){
        echo "Parool peab olema vähemalt 6 tähemärki pikk";
        }
    else {
        $parooli_pikkus=True;
    }

    }

function varasem_olemasolu($email)
{

    if(!empty($_POST['email']))
        {
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM kasutajad WHERE e_mail = '$email'") or die(mysql_error());
        if(mysql_num_rows($query) == 0) 
        {
            $varasem_olemasolu=True;
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Selle e-mailiga on kasutaja juba registreeritud.";
        }
    }
}

function paroolide_kattuvus($parool, $parool_uuesti) 
    {

    if($parool==$parool_uuesti)
        {
            $paroolide_kattuvus=True;
        }
    else{
        echo "Paroolid ei kattu.";  
    }
    }

function NewUser()
    {
    global $sql;
    if (mysql_query( $sql))
        {
        echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0;url=http://localhost/Praks/templates/registreeritud.php'>";
        }
    }
?>
```

Then I have other PHP code where I call necessary functions(They are seperated, because I want to use my functions in other applications too):

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">

<?php

include_once 'init/init.funcs.php';

        $email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
        $eesnimi = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['eesnimi']);
        $perekonnanimi = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['perekonnanimi']);
        $parool =  $_POST['parool'];
        $parool_uuesti =  $_POST['parooluuesti'];
        $salt = rand(10000,99999);
        $hashed_pwd = sha1($parool.$salt);
        $sql="INSERT INTO kasutajad (e_mail, eesnimi, perenimi, parool, salt ) VALUES ('$email','$eesnimi','$perekonnanimi','$hashed_pwd','$salt')";

    emaili_pikkus($email);

    if ($emaili_pikkus=True){
    parooli_pikkus($parool);
    }

    if ($parooli_pikkus=True){
    varasem_olemasolu($email);
    }

    if ($varasem_olemasolu=True){
    paroolide_kattuvus($parool, $parool_uuesti);
    }

    if ($paroolide_kattuvus=True){
    NewUser();
    }
?>
```

And then I have my HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<html>
<head>
<title>Registreerimine</title>
</head>
<body>
<strong>Registreerimiseks täida järgnevad väljad: </strong><br>
<br>
<form method="POST" action="registreerimine4.php">
<table>
<tr><td>Sinu Tieto e-maili aadress: </td><td><input type="text" name="email"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Eesnimi: </td><td><input type="text" name="eesnimi"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Perekonnanimi: </td><td><input type="text" name="perekonnanimi"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Parool: </td><td><input type="text" name="parool"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Parool uuesti: </td><td><input type="text" name="parooluuesti"></td></tr>
</table>
<br>
<input type="submit" value="Registreeri" name="Registreeri">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

init.funcs.php looks like that:

```
<?php

session_start ();

$db = mysql_connect ( 'localhost', 'root', 'aaaa' );

if (! $db) {
    header ( "location: /" );
    die ();
} else {
    mysql_select_db ( 'ta2014' );
}

include_once 'functions/user.funcs.php';
include_once 'functions/survey.funcs.php';

?>
```

It all together should be a registration form and it worked before I made few changes. Before those changes I had my functions defined to work only for this registration form and they had no parameters needed. Also they were nested in each other. My question is how should I write my second PHP code, so it all would work. Right now it creates new user even if some previous condition are not True. It is a long question and I would be very thankful if someone answers me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot of errors in your code:

1. Your functions aren't returning any value. Variables intitalized inside the function will not be available outside it. The best way is to return a boolean value and check that outside

   **The function definition:**

   ```
   function some_func($param1, $param2) {
       if (some_condition) {
           // If everything okay, return TRUE
           return TRUE;
       } else {
           // It's not gonna work with this, so return FALSE
           return FALSE;
       }
   }
   ```

   **Checking the return value:**

   ```
   if (some_func($foo, $bar)) {
       // some_func returned TRUE, do further processing
   }
   ```
2. With `if($var = True)`, you're not actually checking if a variable is true or not. You're **assigning** it the boolean value `True`. You need to write `if($var == True` instead.
3. You're using the deprecated `mysql_*` functions. They're deprecated. Use MySQLi or PDO instead.